# Table `in use` on a mySQL server in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm currently working on a website, and there is a bug that happend a few times already. I know this question has already been asked, but it hasn't been answered.
The problem is the following: a table in the database becomes unusable and probably corrupted.

When i check on phpmyadmin, the table is indicated as `in use`, and i can't open it nor read it's data (if it still exists).

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaj8t.jpg

It is quite possible this bug is due to some interactions with the table, but it is very unlikely that these interactions didn't happen before.

So far, I've done some research and only found one guy with a solution.
I can't tell if it works yet, but he found that his table becoming `in use` was due to the storage engine being 'InnoDB' (same for me), and so i switched it to MyISAM.

Comment: Check the PHPMyAdmin source code to see how and why the *"in use"* message is there..

Comment: @RaymondNijland What do  you mean by source code? If you mean the logs, i unfortunately can't view them as i don't have the rights to enable these (it's gonna change soon)

Comment: *"What do you mean by source code?"* i mean read the PHP/HTML/Javascript code how PHPMyAdmin was build?

Answer (score 0):

You should never change your Innodb storage engine to MyISAM because Innodb has more benefits over MyISAM regarding performance and locking.

Apart from the benefits, if you did the conversion from Innodb to MyISAM it cause many problems and database size get also large. So you must use your previous backup of database which was based on InnoDB storage engine and for this issue goes in PHPMyAdmin, select the desired database, at the bottom, there is a dropdown option of "With Selected" select "Repair Table" from here. Most of the time it resolves this issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed it because i have absolutely no clue about this error and where it comes from. It's the 4th time it happens in like a month, and I have looked all over my code to see if it could corrupt it. The reason I changed to MyISAM is because it fixed it for someone, but also because most of the database is under MyISAM (was done before i arrived). About the 'Repair table', i tried already several times, and apparently I can't because this `in use` table creates an error in the process.

Comment: @tacosanxiety besides performance and locking i am also pretty sure MyISAM is on it way to deprecation as MySQL from MySQL 8.0.16+ it not allowed anymore to use MyISAM in the [internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine)  setting .  Notice the message *"In MySQL 8.0.16 and later, on-disk internal temporary tables always use the InnoDB storage engine; as of MySQL 8.0.16, this variable has been removed and is thus no longer supported. "*  which lends me to believe MyISAM is on it way to deprecation

Comment: @tacosanxiety "In use" issue is normally happened due to large data or disk space issue, If you transformed your database into MyISAM then your database size has already increased, it means more size than the previous database. You must need to optimize your database firstly.  Otherwise Repair trick will not work. My suggestion is to use your previous database backup of Innodb, optimize it by using "ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = 'InnoDB' " and then Repair it.

Comment: When you apply techniques on the right approach then the solution can possible otherwise you will be stuck in some other problem in the future.

Comment: You can optimize your current database as well but if you are sure that this database is in full working conditions and not lost any indexes, because during conversion many problems happen in the database and optimization will not work in such type of databases.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, but having absolutely no clue of what is causing this error, I will just wait and see, even thought MyISAM is not a good solution. My main concern is about finding the problem.